# Is there any way to test CodeIgniter applications modyfing the headers so we emulate a mobile device?

Tags: php, codeigniter, testing, device-emulation

I'm a total newbie to testing, and I'm stuck with this problem.
I need to test some CodeIgniter's controllers, in order to see if the system works correctly, and I need to make it appear like I'm using different types of mobile devices.

I can use the Firefox plugin "Modify Headers", so I can test one by one. But it's an impossible job, I need to automatize the testing.

Is there any way to do it? Any testing software/libraries/something that can help me with this issue so I can detect possible errors?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: You could use; http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

Comment: Thank you. But I don't need to see how it looks on mobile devices. I need to see how determined hundreds of devices would work with determined controllers that get data from a database and see if they process it right. Sorry if I don't explain it properly.